# OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET mvc application that I develop and is working on one of my company's Windows server 2008 R2. The application has been working fine until today when it started giving error

```
OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available
```

Stacktrace:

> [Exception: OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available.]
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OciHandle..ctor(OciHandle parentHandle, HTYPE handleType, MODE ocimode, HANDLEFLAG handleflags) +317
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName) +127
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions) +129
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +40
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +548
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +69
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +470
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +118
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open() +43
>      Account_Statement.DataAccess.PreRetroStatement.GetAltAccount(String accountNo) +102
>      Account_Statement.DataAccess.PreRetroStatement.GetPreRetroStatement(StatementViewModel statementViewModel) +51
>      Account_Statement.Controllers.HomeController.PreRetrofit(StatementViewModel model) +96
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +223
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651516
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155